# Regex for string not containing multiple specific words

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to put together a regex to find when specific words *don't* exist in a string. Specifically, I want to know when "trunk", "tags" or "branches" doesn't exist (this is for a Subversion pre-commit hook). Based on the [Regular expression to match string not containing a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) answer I can easily do this for one word using negative look-arounds:

```
^((?!trunk).)*$
```

It's the "and" operator I'm struggling with and I can't seem to get combinations including the other two words working.

This is running fine in .NET with a single word:

```
var exp = new Regex(@"^((?!trunk).)*$");
exp.IsMatch("trunk/blah/blah");
```

It will return false as it currently stands or true if "trunk" doesn't exist in the path on the second line.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why can't you just do a normal "search for" regex and invert the result instead?

Comment: I'm constrained by only being able to edit the regex, not the surrounding logic.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use a negative [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that asserts the absence of any of the three words somewhere in the input:

```
^(?!.*(trunk|tags|branches)).*$
```

I also slightly rearranged your regex to correct minor errors.

Comment: @S.Serp because a look ahead doesn't consume input, you have to leave something outside to actually match on. If you move the `.*` inside the look ahead, you're left with just `^$`, which literally matches nothing (ie a blank), plus a look ahead that matches *something*, which is an impossibility.

Comment: How would one apply this to multiple lines? So if one of the words `trunk|tags|...` is found in a multiline text, don't return a match for any of those lines.

Comment: @Dalie to work with a multiline string (a single string that includes newlines) add the DOTALL flag so the dot character matches newlines too ie`(?s)^(?!.*(trunk|tags|branches)).*$` or `/^(?!.*(trunk|tags|branches)).*$/m` (the method of enabling flags is language implementation dependent)

Comment: It worked out beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use a "standard" match and look for `!IsMatch`

```
var exp = new Regex(@"trunk|tags|branches");
var result = !exp.IsMatch("trunk/blah/blah");
```

Why persons love to make their life difficult?

Ah... And remember the `ass` principle! http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

So it would be better to write

```
var exp = new Regex(@"\b(trunk|tags|branches)\b");
```

But if you really need a negative lookahed expression, and keeping up with the `ass` principle

```
var exp = new Regex(@"^(?!.*\b(trunk|tags|branches)\b)";
```

Tester: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2uv1g

I'll note that if you are looking for full paths (words separated by `/` or `\`) then

```
var exp = new Regex(@"^(?!.*(^|\\|/)(trunk|tags|branches)(/|\\|$))";
```

Tester: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2uv1p

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the constraint in this case requires the work to be done in the regex and I can't control the code outside this to invert the condition.