# Filter strings that do not contain one of the following strings

Tags: regex

I want to filter strings that do not contain one of the following strings

```
ABCD
IJKL
```

I have tried to create the regex using regex101

https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/1

What is wrong here?

tried also the answer from [Regex for string not containing multiple specific words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801581/regex-for-string-not-containing-multiple-specific-words)

but it did not work
https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/3

Comment: enable `gm` flag..see https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/2

Comment: Anchored regular expressions need `m` flag. Also for matching *all cases* you would need `g` flag.

Comment: It works. https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/4. Now, what is your real environment? Does it allow lookarounds? And please do not delete your identical questions, just update them. If you can use lookarounds, this question is still a dupe of [*Regex for string not containing multiple specific words*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801581/regex-for-string-not-containing-multiple-specific-words).

Comment: So, shall we close this one as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this?

**https://regex101.com/r/gI6sN8/10**

```
(?=ABCD|IJKL)(.*)
(?= // This is a look ahead
ABCD|IJKL // ABCD or IJKL
) // Close the look ahead

(.*) // Get EVERYTHING if the line contains the look ahead and return me that line
```

But your question is a little unclear.  If you can tidy it up and give a sharper description I'm sure we will be able to help you more.

Comment: This phrase finds when one of the substrings string is contained in each string. I was looking for when non of the substring is contained.

Comment: If you able to use GREP, use a -v to invert your match.  Otherwise a Negative Look Behind might be your best approach.