# JavaScript regex for blacklisting words

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, blacklist

I'm trying to write a regex to blacklist certain words. I'm able to create a whitelist like `/^(carrots|onions|corn)$/` but how would I convert that into a blacklist?

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm matching this blacklist against a whole string. For example `"corndog"` should be allowed. I want the regex equivalent of `blacklistArray.indexOf(word) === -1`

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801581/regex-for-string-not-containing-multiple-specific-words

Comment: Thanks—that's similar but different. Please see clarified question and unmark as duplicate if possible.

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew can you please reopen? This is not a duplicate.

Comment: @ryanve: It ***is*** a dupe. See my answer there, (match everything but) *a string equal to some string* section. Your solution: `^(?!(?:carrots|onions|corn)$)` - it will match any string not equal to `carrots`, `onoins`, `corn`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Mine is about matching whole words not subwords. My coworker figured out that the correct pattern for this is  https://gist.github.com/ryanve/004dcaecf1fe4835345385b4d1500c78 Yours is different and not what I asked for in the question. Again, please reopen as this is valuable to the community.

Comment: The `/^(?!(corn|bread)$).+/.test('corn')` code is equal to `/^(?!(corn|bread)$)/.test('corn')`, just `.+` requires at least char.

Comment: The `.+` makes it diffferent. Please reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Use negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*(?:carrots|onions|corn))
```

Comment: That feels close but it also seems to blacklist partial matches. I only want to blacklist exact matches. `/^(?!.*(?:carrots|onions|corn))/.test('corndog')` is false where I'd want that to be true to allow corndog.